# Tkinter image doesn't exist

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am converting a pdf to a bunch of images and displaying it to a tkinter window, but after the pdf conversion I get this error from Tkinter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karee\PycharmProjects\Workspace\pdf_viewer.py", line 25, in <module>
    pdf.image_create(END, image=p)
  File "C:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3728, in image_create
    return self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1700x2200 at 0x5386C10>" doesn't exist
```

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import pdf2image

root = Tk()
pdf1 = 'pdf_path.pdf'
pil_images = []
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(pdf1, "rb"))
pdf_frame = Frame(root).pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
scrol_y = Scrollbar(pdf_frame, orient=VERTICAL)
pdf = Text(pdf_frame, yscrollcommand=scrol_y.set, bg="grey")
scrol_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrol_y.config(command=pdf.yview)

maxPages = inputpdf.numPages
for page in range(1, maxPages, 100):
    pil_images.append(pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf1, dpi=200, first_page=page,
                                                     last_page=min(page + 100 - 1, maxPages), fmt='jpg',
                                                     thread_count=1, userpw=None,
                                                     use_cropbox=False, strict=False, poppler_path="poppler-21.03.0/Library/bin"))

for photo in pil_images:
    for p in photo:
        pdf.image_create(END, image=p)
        pdf.insert(END, '\n\n')

mainloop()
```

When I debugged this program, there were PIL images so I'm not sure what's causing these errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to open it with ```ImageTk.PhotoImage```

Comment: @Sujay How should I do that?

Comment: ```from PIL import ImageTk```, then whenyou open it, use ```file="..." ```

Comment: @Sujay Thanks I was wondering how I would open with ImageTK

Comment: You have to convert the PIL images to [ImageTK.PhotoImage](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) in order to use them with `tkinter`.

Comment: ```im1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\..")```

Comment: From the `ImageTK.PhotoImage` documentation: "The constructor takes either a PIL image, or a mode and a size. Alternatively, you can use the file or data options to initialize the photo image object."

Comment: @Sujay Thanks but now I'm getting a MemoryError, is there a way I can split them up to avoid this?

Comment: @martineau  I'm getting a MemoryError now, is there a way I can split them up to avoid this?

Comment: Not that I know of. See if there's some way to incrementally do what's being done to reduce the amount of memory required all at once. You might also be able to convert the images to a compressed format for display purposes outside the pdf.

Comment: What is the size of your image? Are you using python 32 bits

Comment: @martineau Like, do a loop that loops through 10 images say at once?

Comment: @Sujay I'm not sure the size of the images, I haven't changed anything but the images are being created programmatically so I don't know how to see the size.

Comment: If you can do everything you need to do that way, then yes.

Comment: If your resolution is too much, then it can raise the error

Comment: @Sujay how can I lower the resolution?